# Creating a Fantasy Schedule

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

I'm trying to do what my title says, but there are a few issues that I can't seem to work around.

- It's a 12-team league over 21 weeks with head-to-head matchups.
- I'm aiming for there to be two rivalry weeks where the league is
  partitioned into six pairs (these pairs are the same in both weeks).
- I'm looking for the league to be balanced such that every team plays
  10 other teams twice and one other team once.
- If it matters at all, the odd matchup would go in Week 11, and the two rivalry weeks would be in Weeks 7 and 14.

I'm doing this in Excel, but my knowledge of both Excel and graph theory is failing me. The best way I can come up with is randomly picking matchups and checking to make sure no player has two matchups in the same week. Is there an easier way to make these matchups?

Comment: I don't know what a 'rivalry week' is, so is it fair to say that *every* week, the league is partitioned into six pairs? It's just that you want there to be exactly two weeks with the same partition.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah maybe that's misleading. Thinking about it, if I have 11 distinct partitions into 6 pairs, I can turn that into a schedule. But there's one particular and arbitrary partition that I've already decided I want to use for those rivalry weeks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice graphical approach that works in general when you have $2k$ teams and want to get $2k-1$ partitions of them into $k$ pairs so that no pair occurs in two partitions.

Represent the $12$ teams by $12$ vertices, $11$ of them arranged in a circle with $1$ at the center.

The first match-up draws an edge from the center vertex to one of the radial vertices, and divides the remaining $10$ up into pairs by drawing edges perpendicular to this one:

[image: First match-up]

The second match-up is just a clockwise rotation of the first by 360/11 degrees, shown in red below:

[image: Second match-up]

From here, you keep going in the same way: just rotate the previous match-up by 360/11 degrees to get the next one. Not pictured below because it would just end up a mess of lots of colorful lines, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! This is fantastic! I've been trying to label $K_{12}$, but this is a lot easier.

Comment: This is called Round Robin scheduling (https://nrich.maths.org/1443).

Comment: @JeanMarie You could also call it [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem). (Though its first appearance is probably in Kirkman's 1847 paper "On a Problem in Combinations" and Baranyai proved a more general result.)

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!